# Remove /api/ from vue-router with Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, router

I'm working with vue-router on a laravel project but I need to use laravel router for the api, so I'm wondering on how to pass from vue-router to laravel router when the url contains /api/.
My current web.php look look likes this :

```php
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Comment: You have to create route in api.php file. As All api's route for vuejs should be in api.php file.

Comment: Assume that Laravel processes and picks paths linearly, a definition for your `/api/` route should come before the definiton for your catch-all route for Vue.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by putting my api routes before the vuejs route declaration